# php fatal error "undefined function" for a function in an elgg plugin library

Tags: php, elgg

I am trying to write a plugin for elgg that's similar to the bookmarks plugin. I found out php doesn't do "innerHTML," so I added some code to my plugin's library to accomplish that.  But I am getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function DOMinnerHTML() in
>   /var/www/html/mod/mypluginname/actions/mypluginname/save_address.php
>   on line 71, referer:
>   http://www.example.com/mypluginname/add_address/49

The calling code:

```
mytitle =  $doc->getElementById('myTitle');
if($mytitle){
   $title = DOMinnerHTML($mytitle);
}
```

Line 71 of **/var/www/html/mod/mypluginname/actions/mypluginname/save_address.php** is:

> $title=DOMinnerHTML($mytitle);

The function is in **/var/www/html/mod/mypluginname/lib/mypluginname.php**:

```
function DOMinnerHTML(DOMNode $element)
{
   $innerHTML = "";
   $children  = $element->childNodes;

   foreach ($children as $child)
   {
      $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
   }
   return $innerHTML;
}
```

Any idea why this function isn't considered "defined?"

Comment: did you include or require mypluginname.php ?

Comment: none of the other files calling functions in lib do so, so I didn't. I can try...

Comment: Well, that was it.   thank you! I added require '/var/www/html/mod/mypluginname/lib/mypluginame.php'.  Not sure why the other functions didn't require the require...  If you put this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I will change it to answer, so the topic is closed. Mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include or require mypluginname.php ?

Comment: That shouldn't be marked as correct answer as Evan's one explains proper way of requiring non object oriented libraries in Elgg.

Comment: I did not say how to require or include a file. I just asked him if he did it?

Answer (score 1):

The bookmarks plugin is using the library loading function `elgg_load_library`. This allows you to reference a library by name instead of absolute path, which makes things slightly more flexible.

If you want to use that in your plugin, you'll need to use `elgg_register_library` in start.php.